# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance

Tags: java, android, firebase

My play console told me that I have a guy who made 175 reports for 1 day (**Android 7.0 Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime**) I have the same phone and can't reproduce this error.

Could it be a problem with user's phone? I use last version of gms:playservices, same version of firebase-core and I use this services only for ads

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzb.create (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.zza (SourceFile:28)
  at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.get (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.get (SourceFile:39)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer$$CC.get (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.get (SourceFile)
  at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.zza (SourceFile:68)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze (SourceFile:703)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (SourceFile:328)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (SourceFile:294)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (SourceFile:281)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate (SourceFile:37)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1759)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1734)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo (SourceFile:31)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6420)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6012)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5951)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1710)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Forgot to update post, I've lost this user after app update, never seen this issue anymore